# simple nginx reverse proxy for use with organizr

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Note: Total newbie, learning all this on the fly.
Running on macOS 10.15.2

I've set up nginx to use with organizr and I've been trying to get a reverse proxy to work with no success. I have a domain setup which points to my IP. I have the following in my nginx config file.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mydomain.com;
    root   /path/to/site;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
```

}

As I understand it requests from mydomain.com should be proxied to 127.0.0.1, however I get the default nginx "An error occurred" page. It doesn't even work internally if I navigate to 127.0.0.1. If i hash out the proxy lines I can access locally. But as I'm a total newbie I've no idea what to try. Hopefully somebody awesome can help :)

Comment: does any service running on port 80 ?

Comment: only nginx is running on port 80

Comment: `tail -fn 10 /var/log/nginx*` (oh your on mac :) well check the nginx logs!) and then going to the site and watch the log populate should provide you with more info

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough info to tell you how to fix it, but I can tell you what's wrong. 127.0.0.1 is the ipv4 address of localhost, aka the same machine. The default http port is 80. You have nginx listening on that port but are then passing traffic to the same place, creating an infinite loop. If you followed the default organizr instructions then that is already on port 80 and you don't need to proxy it.